# How to refresh the window to show a new image in pysimlegui

Tags: python, api, python-imaging-library, pysimplegui, bytesio

When I click the button to change the image, the window refresh  does not work. I don't know how to implement it properly. How can I refresh the api with the button. I'm new to pysimplegui; can somebody point me in the correct direction?

```
from io import BytesIO
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image
import requests, json

def image_to_data(im):
    with BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        data = output.getvalue()
    return data

cutURL = 'https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/wholesomememes'
imageURL = json.loads(requests.get(cutURL).content)["url"]
data = requests.get(imageURL).content
stream = BytesIO(data)
img = Image.open(stream)
giy=image_to_data(img)
control_col = sg.Column([
    [sg.Button('next meme', key = '_3_')],])
image_col = sg.Column([[sg.Image(giy, key = '-IMAGE-')]])
layout = [[control_col,image_col]]
window = sg.Window('meme', layout,finalize=True)









while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    
    if event is None:
        break
    if '_3_' in event:
       
       window.refresh()
       
    
window.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `window.refresh()` called to update the GUI if you do some changes to element(s) and you want to update it immediately before the script execute next `window.read()` which also update the GUI.

It is necessary to download next picture from website again by your code, `window.refresh()` won't automatically update new image.

```py
from io import BytesIO
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image
import requests, json

def image_to_data(im):
    with BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        data = output.getvalue()
    return data

def get_data():
    cutURL = 'https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/wholesomememes'
    imageURL = json.loads(requests.get(cutURL).content)["url"]
    data = requests.get(imageURL).content
    stream = BytesIO(data)
    img = Image.open(stream)
    giy = image_to_data(img)
    return giy

control_col = sg.Column([[sg.Button('next meme', key = '_3_')],])
image_col = sg.Column([[sg.Image(get_data(), key = '-IMAGE-')]])
layout = [[control_col,image_col]]
window = sg.Window('meme', layout,finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event is None:
        break
    if event == '_3_':
        window['-IMAGE-'].update(get_data())

window.close()
```

Comment: thankyou finally it is fixed  :)

Comment: Hey do you have any social media where we can talk. If you are comfortable enough to share

Comment: You can post question on https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues, remember fill the form, or you will be rejected.

Comment: thankyou I already raised a issue there. I am new to programming, I just wanted to ask you some question's/ take some advice .